# Git commit history lost and unsure of how to recover

Tags: git, github

Following a disaster where my harddrive corrupted, I was attempting to recover my repositories and ensure they were okay, but it seems that damage has occurred and I have only now noticed the damage.

My code is still intact, but my history, it no longer exists.

```
E:\Programming\exercism>git log --oneline
2c9cbb3 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) .gitignore clojure update
b5a05e1 ?
f2c891c ?
```

(the `?` commits are me trying to figure out what is going on, I did not know at the time that I was commiting the entire repository... because it didn't exist. I commited these changes within VS Code)

My backup of this on one of my main drives suffers the same exact problem, with zero commits (until I made the first, initial commit) and no history, but all of the code still intact.

The repository in question is [here](https://github.com/Xevion/exercism).

I've searched everywhere for the topic at hand to no avail, it seems this problem is rather rare.

**edit:** Further explanation of what the current situation is:

Only 3 commits exist currently in my repo, there should be around 40-60 normally.

My drive incurred damage and I had to transfer everything off it, including repositories, of which some had damage. Perhaps some of them incurred more damage or I did something that ended up deleting or invalidating them, I don't know, but today I went to work on my repository and I noticed that everything was waiting to be committed, and I did so not knowing that my repositories commits no longer existed, or perhaps I had done something beforehand. I still do not know why, since I was sure I had validated that this repository was okay beforehand, but regardless, the repositories changes, 3 commits, now exist on GitHub, where there should be over 30-40 commits. I want to go back to before I had committed and pushed these changes to GitHub, I know it should be possible as I feel that GitHub could and should store changes like this, and it should be rather hard to make such a mistake

**edit 2:** I've decided to give up, and my copy of the original repository is unable to be restored...

[image: missing objects]

Maybe with a bunch of git magic, you could restore half of my commits, which I know they're there, as half of them show up [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArhTT.png)...

I've emailed Git support and I hope for a response back to see if they can do anything, but it's honestly unlikely at this point. Nothing of true value was lost in the end, it was mostly my commit history I wanted back, which sucks, but I guess I'll have to resolve myself to never let this happen again (I was using a portable HDD before, and dropping it create corruption. Installations and repositories which cannot handle this kind of randomized damage are most vulnerable, I've got a portable SSD and I'll look into proper RAID backup and storage for this kind of stuff, as well as to have better comprehension of what I'm doing with my repos).

**edit 3:** I thought I'd update this a long time after, just in case someone runs into the same situation as I: I never fixed this. But luckily, GitHub did provide me with a link to a still working version with all of my commits. I am interested in seeing how I could merge my two histories, but I may revert and then copy over my stuff from right now, as I haven't done much work on the repository in the mean time.

Regardless, GitHub support was very slow - a month passed by before they responded, and I only noticed the email while searched for something completely different. It's nice that they responded at all, but I would be wary that you may not get a expedient response.

Comment: If the repository is available online (on GitHub) and you have pushed your all of your changes, nothing is lost. Simply clone the repository to a new directory on your local file system and you should be good

Comment: I cloned the repo and do not see any of the previous commits. As said below, `git reflog` didn't show any of the previous dozens of commits. The repo is online, yes, but it's like it the commit history got overwritten.

Comment: I looked at the online repository. The history is still there, albeit with commit message `?` – it looks like this didn't get corrupted (you pushed **before** your local repository went AWOL, right?), but has always been this way. How many commits do you expect to be in the repository (currently there are 3)?

Comment: A couple dozen, they've got detailed messages. The `?` messages are me not noticing the glaring issues while I began work again on the repo and committing/pushing, not yet understanding the nature of what was unfolding in front of me in the local repo.

Comment: can you provide the output of `$ git reflog` in the project folder

Comment: https://paste.dimdev.org/ovuviyicon.pl
Most recent actions are as of instructions by Michael in the answer/comment below.

Comment: As far as we (as outsiders) can see, the online repository and the output of `git reflog` look like a regular git repository without any corruption. Sure, the commit message `?` is strange, but all in all, it looks like your repository is valid. You can run `git fsck` to do a "file system check" of your repository, it should report any problems. If it does not, then your repo is fine and nothing got corrupted (maybe you wer working in a different repository?).

Comment: `git fsck` will also tell you about "dangling" objects, these are objects which are no longer reachable from your heads (i.e. branches or tags). If you find any dangling _commits_, use `git log` or `gitk` to inspect them. Maybe you can still find your history

Comment: How did you end up with your linked screenshot? That looks like a proper reflog output and very much like linear history without much branch switching. Can you do a `git log d50b175` and see your history? If so, create a new branch with that commit as tip and push it, then you're good to go and should have your history back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pushed the commits to GitHub, you can recover the history and merged the lost commits in a few steps with the GitHub API:

1. Go to this URL: `https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/events`

This will return/show a JSON object where you can search for the lost commit using CTRL+F and putting the commit message or maybe the author.

2. Copy the full SHA of the commit and paste it in the following command:

```
$ curl -u <user>:<password> -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/recover-commits", "sha":"<full_commit_sha>"}' https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/git/refs
```

Fields:

- `<user>:<password>`: Username and password of your GitHub account.
- `refs/heads/<branch-name>`: ref of the new branch, must have two slashes and start with "refs". What comes after the last slash is the name of the branch
- `sha`: the full sha of the commit, example: "efdec9f65bf420b1af91ad1aded915a42c5fa34d"
- `<repo>`: repository name.

It'll send a request using GitHub API to create a new branch named, in this case, 'recover-commits' that points to that commit.

3. If successful it should return something like this: `HTTP/1.1 201 Created Server: GitHub.com ...`
4. From there you can cherry-pick or merge the commits back into your main branch.

[Source](https://objectpartners.com/2014/02/11/recovering-a-commit-from-githubs-reflog/).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `git reflog` command? this will give you the commit history of even commits that were deleted then you can take the SHA and use it again.

Comment: I entered the command on a cloned repo, my backup repo, and the main repo, and all of them only showed commits that I made recently and none of the lost commits.

Comment: So just take the latest commit SHA and do `git reset <latestCommitSHA>` this will get your history back to there even though for some reason it was deleted

Comment: That didn't do anything as far as I know, and wouldn't, given the nature of the command...

Comment: You say “it didn’t do anything”. Can you show some of the reflog output? It’s really hard to lose commits in git. Did you run the git gc command? Don’t run it.

Comment: Doesn't seem like he ran it based on the reflog output he posted, although the "?" is very odd no idea what that means.
@Xevion another thing you might try is checking out to the commit you want and see if that works `git checkout <SHA>` then if it works make a new branch and merge that branch (or rebase)

Comment: I'm confused mostly as to which SHA you want me to `reflog` on, as well as checkout. I'm not sure that this would do anything, as there are no commits and the SHA I would prefer to revert back to is not available. Perhaps I could find an SHA in my history or something via the URL and revert to that? `git checkout` did not work with the oldest SHA that is available to me.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't add up, if you can see the SHA then you should be able to access the commit, this means it is in memory. Maybe your memory is corrupted. In terms of where to go, whatever commit you want, pick one

Comment: Well, the commits I want to access do not exist in the logs. It's like my Git repo up and deleted it self, it no longer exists. During this state of nonexistence, I did not notice, pushed these "changes" to Github, and my local repo doesn't see any previous commits, of which there where many dozens. These 3 commits aren't the ones I'm looking for.

Comment: Not really sure how that's possible, but try what is suggested above, pull from the repo up to the commit that wasn't corrupted then force push
https://serverfault.com/questions/117255/git-pull-specific-revision-from-remote-repository

Comment: I don't know of any uncorrupted commits, I don't have any in my chrome history and I can't find any in URLs or anything of the like, either. No idea where I would find one, either.

Comment: try `git reflog @{1.day.ago}` then a week then a month, you can also put dates in, at some point you should find an uncorrupted commit. Or like was suggested just delete it and clone it again